# Minimum eigenvalue of One-dimensional Schrodinger Operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, schrodinger-operators, unbounded-operators

Consider the One dimensional Schrodinger Operator

$$
-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)
$$

Where the Potential Function $V$ is of the form $V(x) = x^4 - a^2x^2$ , $a \in \mathbb{R} $.
Now of course,the minimum eigenvalue $E_0 \geq -a^4/4$ , since $-a^4/4$ is the minimum of $V$.
My Question is : Can we Improve this bound for $a$ sufficiently large?
Thanks in advance for any comment,suggestion or reference in that direction.

Answer (score 5):

The Löwdin method to obtain lower bounds to energy eigenvalues of the Schrödinger equation has been reviewed in [Lower Bounds to Energy Eigenvalues](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-1659-7_21#page-1) (1976). It has been applied to the quartic potential in [Upper and Lower Bounds to the Eigenvalues of Double-Minimum Potentials](http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/pages/cbi/annik/revistas/1965.pdf) (1965). See table I, where the coefficient $a$ is given by $a^2=-v_2 v_4^{-2/3}$ and then the lower bound is $\frac{1}{2}E v_4^{-1/3}$ with $E$ the "level 0 energy" from table I. For example, for $a=2.6375$ I find $E_0\geq-8.53234$, well above $-a^4/4=-12.0981$.

Answer (score 1):

If you rescale $x\leftrightarrow y=ax$, the eigenvalue equation is transformed into
$$-v''+a^5(y^4-y^2)=aEv.$$
The potential $y^4-y^2$ has **two** equal wells at $y_0=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}2$, where it takes the value $-\frac14$. When $a>\!\!>1$, the fundamental energy satisfies the asymptotics $aE_0\sim-\frac14 a^5$. Therefore, as you said $E_0\sim-\frac14 a^4$. However, because there are two wells, the operator has two eigenvalues $E_0,E_1$ separated by an exponentially small (in $a$) quantity ; this is a consequence of semi-classical analysis. Because of Krein-Rutmann's Theorem, $E_0$ must be simple, and therefore $E_1$ is simple too.

I am not a specialist of semi-classical analysis and therefore cannot give you a reference. This is a vast domain, studied by phisicists and by mathematicians.

Comment: while semiclassics will certainly give a reliable estimate on the energy level, I have not seen this method capable of giving a rigorous lower bound (for upper bounds one has the Rayleigh-Ritz variational treatment, lower bounds are much more tricky)